# Azure Logic Apps - Do Until Count & Timeout property

Tags: loops, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using DO UNTIL action to iterate over some data until a condition is met to exit the loop. I'm bit confused with the usage of "Count" and "Timeout". Does the count mean the loop iterates only 10 times or does it mean number of retries if it's a long running process.

In my testing I found the loop runs for the value specified in the count (in this case 10). If I want to iterate over a dynamic collection when the count is not known how do I set count?

[image]

Comment: You cannot set count to any unknown value. You need to test for another criteria. What is the condition when the loop should be exited?

Comment: You can use an expression in the "Count"-property to set it equal to the number of iterations in your dynamic collection by casting the collection as an array and using the Length-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting count/timeoutis the equivalent of

```
int c = 0;
Time t = utcNow();

do {

   c++;
} until (foo || c >= 10 || t.addTimeSpan(PT1H) <= utcNow();
```

Comment: it is ridiculous they don't have a tooltip on the UI